# What is the most efficient method to get the last modification time of every file in a git revision?

Tags: python, git, time

I want to programmatically list the name and last modification time of every file in a certain revision.
Running `git log` for every file, [as suggested here](https://serverfault.com/questions/401437/how-to-retrieve-the-last-modification-date-of-all-files-in-a-git-repository) is very slow.
Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Running the script below on a non-trivial repo ([SDL](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL)) takes 59s on my machine.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import subprocess
import time

commit = "HEAD"

start = time.time()

file_names = subprocess.check_output(["git", "ls-tree", "--name-only", "-r", commit], text=True).strip().split("\n")

print(f"[{time.time() - start:.4f}] git ls-tree finished")

file_times = list(datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "-1", "--pretty=format:%cI", commit, "--", name], text=True).strip()) for name in file_names)

print(f"[{time.time() - start:.4f}] git info finished")
```

Comment: This isn't really a Python issue as the time is mostly being consumed by your *git* command

Comment: Perhaps you should consider going the other way around.... Instead of taking every file and doing a log on it, you could consider doing a single `git log` and then run `git ls-tree` on each commit and take notice of the things that _changed_ (by checking object ids of blobs) against the commit you care.... Every time you see a difference you note that it was on the commit you are checking at the time that the file last changed.... It should be a smaller list as you dig deeper in the commit list from log. That creates a single walk.... I would expect it to be faster.

Comment: Also, and as an extension of my previous comment, I think you will need to enforce that git provides a list of commits in chronological order.... I am not really sure if git does this by default.

Comment: @eftshift0 I tried your suggestion, but because the last modification time of some files go back more then 10 years ago, there was no run time improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea is to postprocess `git log --name-status` with whatever per-commit info you want and look for the first occurrence of names you're interested in. The all-of-them version:

```
 git log --name-status --pretty=%ci | awk -F$'\t' '
         NF==1 { stamp=$0; next }
         !seen[$2]++ { print stamp,$0 }
' | sort -t$'\t' -k2,2
```

and as always season to taste. Are you running on spinning rust? I do that on the SDL default checkout with a cheap ssd it takes 0.548s, so more than a hundred times faster. But then, it's doing 1500+ times fewer walks through history so there's that.

Comment: I'm not running on "spinning rust", but on "thinking sand" ;)
Modifying my python script to use `git log --name-status` reduces the run time to less then 1 second. Thanks for that!

Comment: Yah, my nice new 5600x3d is a li'l bit of a beast, it runs your original in 21.3s, your updated one in 0.75s.

Comment: Loved the approach, @jthill :+1:

Answer (score 1):

After creating a python script that used multiple `git` command calls, then added support for using `pygit2` instead *if available* and seeing how **slow** using `git` command calls is when comparing them (not because `git` is slow to do `git` stuff, let me be clear.... It's the creation/destruction of process overhead + reopening a repo multiple times that is making it lag so much), I would advice on trying to get this done with `pygit2`

My project, as a reference: https://github.com/eantoranz/git-duplicate

Not that you will be able to use it to your needs but you can run it using `pygit2` and using binary `git` (there's an option to avoid using `pygit2`) and see the difference in performance.... I would sum up the difference like this: **no contest**.

Also, you should consider, as I said in a comment, to turn the process around and have a single log call and then run `git ls-tree -r <some-commit>` over each commit to check what is changed (list of pending things should be shorter as you go down the revisions).... Then you can get the information about the relevant commits.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, and sharing your pain! :)
Using `git log --name-status --pretty=...`, I am able to do this without requiring extra python libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion by @jthill, I ended up with the following Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import subprocess
import time

commit = "HEAD"

start = time.time()

commit_paths = set(subprocess.check_output(["git", "ls-tree", "--name-only", commit], text=True).strip().split())

print(f"[{time.time() - start:.4f}] git ls-tree finished")

path_times = {}

git_log_out = subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "--name-status", '--pretty=time=%cI'], text=True).splitlines(keepends=False)
current_time = None
for line in git_log_out:
  if not line:
    continue
  if line.startswith("time="):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(line.removeprefix("time="))
    continue
  mod_type, paths = line.split(maxsplit=1)
  assert current_time is not None
  for path in paths.split():
    if path in commit_paths and path not in path_times:
      path_times[path] = current_time

print(f"[{time.time() - start:.4f}] git log finished")
```

Its runtime is around 0.85 seconds on my machine.